# Does this custom implemented python Read Eval Print loop is equivalent to python REPL

Tags: python, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop, dynamic-languages

I am trying to implement python REPL.

```
while True:
    exec("print repr("+raw_input(">>")+ ")")
```

Test Outputs:

```
>>1+1
2
>>"foo "+"bar"
'foo bar'
>>a=3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Projects/python/custom_interpreter.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec("print repr("+raw_input(">>")+ ")")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: repr() takes no keyword argument
```

Apparently a=3 is evaluated as keyword argument not as assignment operation. so I changed the code as follows

```
import traceback
import sys
while True:
    cmd = raw_input(">>>")
    try:
        exec "print repr("+ cmd + ")"
    except TypeError:
        try:
            exec cmd
        except Exception as e:
            sys.stdout.write(traceback.format_exc())
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stdout.write(traceback.format_exc())
```

Test Outputs:

```
>>>a=1
>>>a
1
>>>b=2
>>>b+a
3
>>>"foo "+"bar"
'foo bar'
>>>"foo "+1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Projects/spoj/python/MIXTURES/stack.py", line 9, in <module>
    exec cmd
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>>exit()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is the above code gives the same functionality of python REPL ?

Comment: You didn't implement the `_` and your code doesn't support multiline blocks.

Comment: why not using `print eval(raw_input(">>"))`?

Comment: I think you need try to `eval` string first and `exec` it only if `eval` fails.

Comment: Take a look into this standard modules: [code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e729b946cc03/Lib/code.py) and [codeop](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e729b946cc03/Lib/codeop.py)